# C# XNA firing bullets using array

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

Apparantly I have to show research efforts (and be clearer)?!?...

I have been trying to make a top-down space shooter from scratch using XNA. I have done this quite a few times in the past but havent been coding for a while and this is catching me out again. I am having a problem making the bullets fire how I want them too (I want a maximum specified number of bullets eg.5 on screen at any one time).

I have read many many articles on using arrays but for some reason I cannot see why they only appear as one bullet. I have debugged to the best of my ability and see that it seems they are all being created and 'fired' when space if pushed, however it seems they are all drawn in the same position and hence look like one bullet. Interestingly, the higher i set my 'maxBullets' variable the faster the bullets travel, as if the position -= speed is being applied to all of them each time I create a new Bullet1.

Can any one please help me find the solution. If you need any info if I have left something out, please just let me know. All help appreciated. Thanks :)

Code is below:

```
     using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

        namespace AlienAttacks
        {
            public class Player
            {
                Texture2D texture, bulletTexture1;
                KeyboardState kbState;


                public Vector2 position;
                public int turnSpeed = 15, backSpeed = 2, forwardSpeed = 3;
                Rectangle gameScreenBounds;

                public int frameWidth, frameHeight, currentFrameX, currentFrameY;
                Rectangle drawnRect;

                Bullet[] bullets;
                Bullet bullet1;
                public int maxBullets = 3; // this will actually allow one extra bullet due to array starting at zero
                public int bulletSpeed = 4;
                public float FireTimer = 0.0f, FireRate = 0.8f;

                public Player(Texture2D Texture, int FrameWidth, int FrameHeight, Rectangle GameScreenBounds, Texture2D BulletTexture1)
                {
                    texture = Texture;
                    frameWidth = FrameWidth;
                    frameHeight = FrameHeight;
                    gameScreenBounds = GameScreenBounds;
                    bulletTexture1 = BulletTexture1;
                    bullet1 = new Bullet(bulletTexture1, bulletSpeed);
                    bullets = new Bullet[maxBullets];
                    for (int i = 0; i < maxBullets; i++)
                    {
                        bullets[i] = bullet1;  
                    }
                }

                public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
                {
                    drawnRect = new Rectangle(currentFrameX * frameWidth, currentFrameY * frameHeight, frameWidth, frameHeight);
                    kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

        // Keyboard Controls
                    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && position.X > gameScreenBounds.Left)
                    {
                        position.X -= turnSpeed;
                    }
                    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && position.X + frameWidth < gameScreenBounds.Right)
                    {
                        position.X += turnSpeed;
                    }
                    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && position.Y > gameScreenBounds.Top)
                    {
                        currentFrameX = 1;
                        position.Y -= forwardSpeed; 
                    }
                    else
                        currentFrameX = 0;
                    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && position.Y + frameHeight < gameScreenBounds.Bottom)
                    {
                        position.Y += backSpeed;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < maxBullets; i++)
                    {
                        bullets[i] = bullet1;
                        bullets[i].Update(gameTime);        
                    }
                    FireTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < maxBullets; i++)
                        {

                            if (FireTimer >= FireRate)
                            {

                                if (!bullets[i].IsAlive)
                                {
                                    bullets[i].IsAlive = true;
                                    bullets[i].position = position;
                                    FireTimer = 0.0f;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }





                }

                public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, drawnRect, Color.White);

                    for (int i = 0; i < maxBullets; i++)
                    {
                        bullets[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
                    }

                }
            }
        }


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

    namespace AlienAttacks
    {
        public class Bullet
        {
            public Texture2D texture;
            public Vector2 position;
            public int speed;
            public bool IsAlive = false;


            public Bullet(Texture2D Texture, int Speed)
            {
                texture = Texture;

                speed = Speed;

            }

            public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                if (IsAlive)
                {
                    position.Y -= speed;
                    // if bullet goes off top of screen...
                    if (position.Y - texture.Height < 0)
                    {
                        BulletDead();
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
            {
                if (IsAlive)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
            }

            public void BulletDead()
            {
                IsAlive = false;
            }
        }
    }


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace AlienAttacks
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Rectangle gameScreenBounds;

        Texture2D hudBGTexture;
        Rectangle hudRect;
        int hudPositionY;

        Texture2D p1Texture, p1bulletTexture1;
        Player player1;
        Vector2 player1StartPosition;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1600;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 900;
            //graphics.IsFullScreen = true;




            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            hudRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, 100);
            hudPositionY = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight - hudRect.Height;
            gameScreenBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight - hudRect.Height);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            hudBGTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("hud");

            p1bulletTexture1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("shot");
            p1Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("red");
            player1 = new Player(p1Texture, 144, 104, gameScreenBounds, p1bulletTexture1);
            player1StartPosition = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2 - player1.frameWidth / 2, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight - hudRect.Height - player1.frameHeight);
            player1.position = player1StartPosition;


        }

            /// <summary>
            /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
            /// all content.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void UnloadContent()
            {
                // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
            /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
            protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                // Allows the game to exit
                if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                    this.Exit();

                player1.Update(gameTime);

                base.Update(gameTime);
            }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

            SpriteBatch targetBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            RenderTarget2D target = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            player1.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.Draw(hudBGTexture, new Vector2(0, hudPositionY), Color.WhiteSmoke);
            spriteBatch.End();

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            targetBatch.Begin();
            targetBatch.Draw(target, new Rectangle(0, 0, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height), Color.White);
            targetBatch.End();



            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each item in your array points to the one instance.

```
bullet1 = new Bullet(bulletTexture1, bulletSpeed);
bullets = new Bullet[maxBullets];
for (int i = 0; i < maxBullets; i++)
{
    bullets[i] = bullet1;  
}
```

Should be like this:

```
bullets = new Bullet[maxBullets];
for (int i = 0; i < maxBullets; i++)
{
    bullets[i] = new Bullet(bulletTexture1, bulletSpeed);  
}
```